# How to do XML transformation in Mule Data weave 2.0

Tags: xml, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have two result set from DB one is in Payload and another in another variable. I am trying to iterate over multiple result set to form the xml. During the second iteration I need to get multiple entity tags from second result set.

Payload:

```json
[
    {
        "Version": "1.0",
        "ID": "VKP",
        "Password": "VKP",
        "Username": "VKP",
        "id": "123456789",
        "Amount": "1000",
        "StreetAddress": "Oaks Ave"
    }
]
```

`vars.borrowerResult`:

```json
[
    {
        "firstname": "Vinoy",
        "lastname" :"VKP"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Kevin",
        "lastname" :"Peter"
    }
]
```

Current code:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
fun StreetAddressSizeCheck(data) = if(data != null and sizeOf(data) > 30) data[0 to 29] else data
---
DRIVERequest @(version : "1.00") : {
    Authentication @(ID : "*****", Password : "******", Username : "******") : null,
    BatchRequest : payload map {
        Mortgage @(id : $.id, Amount : $.Amount) : {
            Property @(StreetAddress : StreetAddressSizeCheck($.StreetAddress)) : null,
            //Below is the place i am trying to add the code to iterate over variabe.
            // If there are multiple objects i need to get as much entries are there in Array.
            vars.borrowerResult map{
                Borrower @(firstname :$.firstname ,lastname : $.lastname) : null, 
            }
    }
}
```

Expected XML Output is

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<DRIVERequest version="1.00">
  <Authentication ID="*****" Password="******" Username="******"/>
  <BatchRequest>
    <Mortgage id="123456789" Amount="1000">
      <Property StreetAddress="Oaks Ave"/>
      <Borrower firstname="Vinoy" lastname="VKP"/>
      <Borrower firstname="Kevin" lastname="Peter"/>
    </Mortgage>
  </BatchRequest>
</DRIVERequest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
//2nd Result set in Variable 
var borrowerResult= [
{
    "firstname": "Vinoy",
    "lastname" :"VKP"
},
{
    "firstname": "Kevin",
    "lastname" :"Peter"
}
]

fun StreetAddressSizeCheck(data) = if(data != null and sizeOf(data) > 30) data[0 to 29] else data
---
DRIVERequest @(version : "1.00") : {
Authentication @(ID : "*****", Password : "******", Username : "******") : null,
BatchRequest : payload map {
Mortgage @(id : $.id, Amount : $.Amount) : {
  Property @(StreetAddress : StreetAddressSizeCheck($.StreetAddress)) : null,
   (borrowerResult map{
             Borrower @(firstname :$.firstname ,lastname : $.lastname) : null, 
 })

 }
 }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Ah.. Salim posted the same answer. Should've refreshed the page :) I was busy cleaning up the formatting heh.

```
output application/xml
fun StreetAddressSizeCheck(data) = if(data != null and sizeOf(data) > 30) data[0 to 29] else data
---
DRIVERequest @(version : "1.00") : {
    Authentication @(ID : "*****", Password : "******", Username : "******") : null,
    BatchRequest : payload map {
        Mortgage @(id : $.id, Amount : $.Amount) : {
            Property @(StreetAddress : StreetAddressSizeCheck($.StreetAddress)) : null,
            (vars.borrowerResult map {
                Borrower @(firstname :$.firstname ,lastname : $.lastname) : null, 
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The parenthesis around the map are necessary because they basically stand for "expand this out into the parent object". Without them, you would need to set a key for the array to be assigned to.

Comment: Thanks. In fact same answer :)